# how to iterate reference variable inside a class

Tags: c#

I tried to use the code `PropertyInfo[]` but the code is not getting any attribute. Because the attribute inside `class1` is just a reference variable

```
 public readonly subClass1 sClass1;
 public readonly subClass2 sClass2;
 public readonly subClass3 sClass3;

 public class1()//constructor
 {
        sClass1= new subClass1();

        sbClass2= new subClass2();

        sClass3= new subClass3();
 }
```

My problem is, i can't access those 3 classes just by using `PropertyInfo[]`

but my i can access it using

```
        Type type = typeof(class1);
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var f = field.GetType().GetFields();
            i++;
        }
```

But this code is not working as i want to work, they can get the class but i can't get the property of every `subClass`

What i want is something like this

```
var f = class1.sClass1;
```

my variable f will now hold the every property of a class.

I'm sorry if i can't explain it well. If you want to ask something, just comment below

by the way this is the inside code of every `subClass`

```
        public string X{ get; set; }
        public string Y{ get; set; }
        public string Width { get; set; }
        public string Length { get; set; }
```

Comment: can you please post the structure of `subClass1` ,`subClass2`, `subClass3`

Comment: the last code is the structure of the subClass1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do it recursively

```
 void GetFields(Type type) 
{
foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance
 | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", fieldInfo.FieldType.Name, fieldInfo.Name);
  if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsClass)
    GetFields(fieldInfo.FieldType);
}
```

You have to use **`field.FieldType`** instead of using **`field.GetType()`**

Comment: hi thanks for this, i'll comment my further question here. Please answer it. Thanks, i'll accept your answer after that, im really thank you

Comment: since i only have public variable, am i only using BindingFlags.Public?

Comment: hello, why the variable inside the class return like this 
`<Width>k__BackingField` it should `Width` only

Comment: Yeah for public fields you could use GetFields() . By Deafult it picks up only public fields. Now  the reason why you are getting  `<Width>k__BackingField` is beacuse of  the backing fields generated by the compiler for the properties.

Comment: for example, i have your looping code, and the code is working, how can i set the value for each attribute in a subClass. I tried the getValue but the variable type is mismatch

Comment: @CodeSlayer please post the code ie how you are setting the value and where you are getting the variable type mismatch

Comment: `var index = 0;`

`foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))`
            {
              
                var i = 0;
                PropertyInfo[] properties = fieldInfo.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                {
                    var newVal = property.GetValue(class1.SubClass1, null).ToString();
i++;
}

Comment: why are you still using `fieldInfo.GetType()` as it will give the type of the field not the type of the field it is referring to . As i said in my answer use `field.FieldType` instead.

Comment: because it cannot convert to propertyinfo

Comment: i used this to set the new value, or is there any code in fieldtype to set value on the variables

Comment: `field.FieldType` gives you a type on which you could call `GetProperties` If you still have more questions please post it as a separate question  than continuing in comments

Comment: thanks for your time and knowledge, really appreciate it